# How to reconfigure lists located in separate columns by way of alternating the columns being transferred for each row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set that consists of columns A-D. Values in A and D are the same respectively, as are B and C. It is listed for the purposes of A correlating to B, and C to D. What I would like to do is to be able to create a new two column list using the combinations of A&B and C&D. But I need them to go in the order they are originally listed i.e. new sheet, Row 1 A&B, Row 2 C&D, Row 3 A&B etc.

[image]

At first I tried simple filters and sorting, but due to the range of the data set at times, it makes the values that need to be close too each other too far. I tried a few failed splices and cuts. I had hoped there would just be a built in excel function.

```
Option Explicit

Sub combineList()

Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lRow
        If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            If Cells(i, 9) = "" Then
                Cells(i, 9) = Cells(i, 1)
                Cells(i, 10) = Cells(i, 2)
                Cells(i + 1, 9) = Cells(i, 4)
                Cells(i + 1, 10) = Cells(i, 5)
            Else
            i = i + 1
                Cells(i, 9) = Cells(i, 1)
                Cells(i, 10) = Cells(i, 2)
                Cells(i + 1, 9) = Cells(i, 4)
                Cells(i + 1, 10) = Cells(i, 5)
            'i = i - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

First attempt, trying to get it to skip over rows for C&D.

```
Sub newMethod()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
With ws
lRow = .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lRow Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            Cells(i, 9) = Cells(i, 1)
            Cells(i, 10) = Cells(i, 2)
            'i = i + 1
        End If
    Next i

    For j = 2 To lRow Step 2
        If Cells(j, 1) = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            Cells(j + 1, 9) = Cells(j, 4)
            Cells(j + 1, 10) = Cells(j, 5)
            'j = j + 1
        End If
    Next j
End With
End Sub
```

As stated above, to be able to reorganize the list by "shuffling" it together. Basically each row split into two. My attempts have ended with loops that just constantly overwrite themselves.

Comment: You provide no examples of your source data.  But do you have blank cells within the data?  If not, why are you testing for that?

Comment: We need to see some sample data to evaluate what your code is doing.

Comment: @PeterT I added a picture of what I intend to do, the code just writes over itself, not skipping to next row when writing.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I added an example. I do tend to have blank cells from time to time, just force of habit.Please disregard the `Step -1` and `Step 2`. I just saw them used elsewhere and was giving them a go. I used it with and without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain your desired results using formulas.

It is a matter of deriving the mathematics of obtaining the correct row/col numbers in sequence.

```
F2: =INDEX($A:$D,FLOOR(ROWS($1:2)/2,1)+1,MOD(ROWS($1:2),2)*2+1)
G2: =INDEX($A:$D,FLOOR(ROWS($1:2)/2,1)+1,MOD(ROWS($1:2),2)*2+2)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry to bother you after you have already provided a solution, but do you have any links for reading/study material for some of that. Not going to lie, I have never seen `MOD` or `FLOOR` before. And thank for the answer kind sir.

Comment: @sTan_The_mAn Start with the MS Excel Help resource.